# I can not install any software

Tags: software-center

I am new to Ubuntu. During installation of software from Ubuntu software center it shows that there is no internet connection whereas I can access to any website. Using terminal the same problem appears. I installed Ubuntu 12.04 by windows installer. How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Change the servers for downloading updates in the `software sources` to `Main server` and try if this fixes it.

[image]

You get here by going to the top left with your cursor (go to the text `software sources`) and choose `edit`, `prefences`.

After opening the Software Sources Window select the "Download From" option and the last option let's you select a new server. You can choose to do a automatic "best server for you" method which checks which server is closer to you or a manual selection where you can select a server from a list.

Comment: If you can add the following: After opening the Software Sources Window select the "Download From" option and the last option let's you select a new server. You can choose to do a automatic "best server for you" method which checks which server is closer to you or a manual selection where you can select a server from a list.

Comment: sure @LuisAlvarado